# Is there a way to use the same Facebook app to debug production URL and localhost?

Tags: facebook, visual-studio-debugging

Every time I create a new Facebook app that integrates with a website I end up creating two, one to test in my debug environment (localhost/mysite) and another for production (www.mysite.com). This always comes in handy for the deployment/QA phase where the app is online, but you are still debugging. The downside, is that you have two apps to change settings, and allow/disallow it each time you switch. Would be a great speed increase if this were possible. Any way to use the same app?

> My projects are in ASP.NET MVC on Windows (IIS) and VS2010.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me, hope it's useful to others. There are couple of steps involved:

- **Hosts**

  Add a subdomain of your URL to the hosts file

  `127.0.0.1 debug.mysite.com`
- **Visual Studio 2010**

  I always use the VS Development Server, it allows me to simply debug by pressing F5. Use a *Specific port* and set the *Start URL* to the hosts file with port.

  [image: Visual Studio Settings]
- **Facebook Developer Dashboard**

  In the Facebook Dashboard, choose your app and then click on Settings on the left menu. Add your domain to the *App Domains* (this allows you to use all subdomains), and the production URL in the *Site Url*.

  [image: Facebook Settings]